# Create a new php array with dynamic key made from another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, key

Here's my problem: I'm trying to create an array from a form than I later put in a session:

```
<?PHP

$_SESSION['tablevalues'] = [
    'users' => $_POST['user'],
    'bank-affiliated' => [
        'user' => $_POST['user'],
        'bank' => $_SESSION['bank']
    ]
];

$bankperuser = [];
foreach ($_SESSION['tablevalues']['bank-affiliated'] as $key => $value) {

    $bankperuser[$key] = [
        $key => $value
    ];
}
?>

<div class="data">
    <div>
        <h3>Bank per user</h3>
        User
        <?php foreach ($bankperuser as $key => $value) { ?>
            User: 
           <?php echo $value['user'];?>
           Banks:
           <?php echo $value['banks'];?>
       <?php } ?>
   </p>  
</div>
```

Ideally, my array would have this structure:

```
<?PHP

$_SESSION['tablevalues'] = [
    'bank-affiliated' => [
        $_POST['user'] => $_SESSION['bank']
    ]
];
```

Which would be translated in something like:

```
array(2) {
    ['marco']=>
    string(1) 6
    ['matteo']=>
    string(1) 2
  }
```

But so far the closest result that I was able to obtain is something like that:

```
array(1) {
  ["user"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "matteo"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "barco"
  }
}
string(4) "user"
array(1) {
  ["bank"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
string(4) "bank"
```

Which is not useable form my point of view because, if I loop through the result of this array, I'm not sure if I would able to marge this array and create the result that I would like to reach, which, at the end of the day, is something very easy, in the line of:

User: Marco - Banks: 6

User: Matteo - Banks: 8

Wrapped in HTML and ready to go. Now I certainly miss something and I bet it is relatively easy to spot, can anyone could give me a hint?

UPDATE:

I was able to do this:

```
$bankperuser = array_combine($_SESSION['tablevalues']['bank-affiliated']["user"], $_SESSION['tablevalues']['bank-affiliated']["bank"]);
```

Then I later loop through:

```
 <h3>Bank per user</h3>
 <p>Our banks and users:
    <?php foreach ($bankperuser as $key => $value) { ?>
        <p>User: <?php echo $key; ?></p>
        <p>Banks: <?php echo $value; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
</p>
```

Which would be ideal, except for the fact that it will remove duplicates.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to pull off here. Can you show a sample structure of `$_POST['user']` and `$_SESSION['bank']`?

Comment: @El_Vanja I added the update to better show what I would like to obtain, what do you think about it? And my solution?

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear since I don't know the structure of your data, so I can only guess. Same goes for the solution, though I can say that it seems rather fragile to me. It looks as though you rely on the arrays to be perfectly ordered with the matching data.